# How to install python-devel 2.7 on RHEL 5.5

Tags: python

I've install python 2.7 by compiling the python27 source code. When I install python-devel 2.7 from rpm package, the following errors occur:

> root#rpm -ivh  python-devel-2.7.5-8.3.1.x86_64.rpm
>
> error: Failed dependencies:   /usr/bin/python2.7 is needed by
>   python-devel-2.7.5-8.3.1.x86_64   python = 2.7.5 is needed by
>   python-devel-2.7.5-8.3.1.x86_64   python(abi) = 2.7 is needed by
>   python-devel-2.7.5-8.3.1.x86_64   python-base = 2.7.5-8.3.1 is needed
>   by python-devel-2.7.5-8.3.1.x86_64    rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) <= 4.4.6-1
>   is needed by python-devel-2.7.5-8.3.1.x86_64

python -v shows the right version
Python 2.7.8 (default, Nov 25 2016, 18:13:09)

Any suggestions on installing python-devel 2.7?

Comment: Where did you install python27 when you compiled from source? Can you show `which python` to see if you're checking the right python version that yum is also trying to use?

Comment: root# which python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python -> python2.7

Comment: Okay, can you then run `/usr/bin/python2.7 -V`?

Comment: sure.  `[root@localhost ~]# /usr/bin/python2.7 -v
...Python 2.7.8 (default, Nov 25 2016, 18:13:09) `

Comment: Hmm ok. I've been doing a bit of reading on this issue and it seems that if you compiled and installed python from source, you shouldn't then need to install python-devel on top (as the tools should have been built with your source build). Can you check to see if you have `libpython2.7.so` in your python lib directory (e.g. if you installed to `/usr/local/bin/` then check: `/usr/local/lib` )